# How do I achieve this pulled-aside look?

Tags: html, css

I need to achieve the following look:

[image]

Because I'm using a `CMS`, the structure I have to work with is

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="ebrochure"><!--This is the box pulled off to the right, with "Ready to start .."--></div>
<h1><!--This is the "The Easiest Way to Make an Impact" header--></h1>
<h3><!--This is the "A Gift in Your Will or Living Trust" header--></h3>
<p><!--This is the "Interested in ..." paragraph--></p>
</div>
```

Is that look achievable? If so, how?

Comment: Have you tried `float: right;` in your CSS?

Comment: To see what looks are achievable where you can view the page source, check out: http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/alldesigns/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer for you because I have to leave now but here is a start and some useful resources

http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing
http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/floating-clearing-css/

Sorry i was unable to finish it! If you don't get more answers in the mean time, comment back and let me know and if I am around I can help you some more.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">

    <div class="ebrochure">
      <div id="salepoint"><p>Ready to start..Aliquid dolores conclusionemque ei ius, dico cibo ut sea, maiorum fastidii consequuntur quo ex. Vix quas temporibus ex. Consulatu appellantur sea id, usu an sumo saperet lucilius. Mel atqui inani at, ea ius choro insolens convenire. Te usu pericula adversarium.Qui tale dolore dissentias cu. Libris moderatius te est. No nam audiam singulis sapientem, eum ei laoreet legendos delicatissimi. Mei atqui sensibus percipitur no. Sed et persius gloriatur inciderint, et sea mazim impetus.An duo posse numquam offendit, recteque efficiantur reprehendunt mea ex. Est discere volumus eu, illud conceptam mei ad. Suas liber complectitur ea sit. An populo facete laoreet quo, ad fabellas expetenda referrentur est. Augue cotidieque vel an. Vix aliquid vivendo liberavisse ut, etiam euripidis ius no. Ei audiam corpora eos. Nihil eirmod omnesque vis et. Ut vide mundi definitiones vix, voluptua constituto mel</p><!--This is the box pulled off to the right, with "Ready to start .."--></div>
    </div>

  <h1><b>The Easiest Way</b><br> <i>to Make an Impact</i><!--This is the "The Easiest Way to Make an Impact" header--></h1>
        <h3>A Gift in Your Will or Living Trust<!--This is the "A Gift in Your Will or Living Trust" header--></h3>
    <div id="about">
        <p>Interested in helping blah with our mission bu tfeel overwhelmed by the thought of writing another check or giving your assets today? orem ipsum dolor sit amet, est tation minimum delicata et, per an ridens eruditi. Conceptam dissentias mea an, eam at definiebas omittantur, vis id autem labores erroribus. Aliquid dolores conclusionemque ei ius, dico cibo ut sea, maiorum fastidii consequuntur quo ex. Vix quas temporibus ex. Consulatu appellantur sea id, usu an sumo saperet lucilius. Mel atqui inani at, ea ius choro insolens convenire. Te usu pericula adversarium.Qui tale dolore dissentias cu. Libris moderatius te est. No nam audiam singulis sapientem, eum ei laoreet legendos delicatissimi. Mei atqui sensibus percipitur no. Sed et persius gloriatur inciderint, et sea mazim impetus.An duo posse numquam offendit, recteque efficiantur reprehendunt mea ex. Est discere volumus eu, illud conceptam mei ad. Suas liber complectitur ea sit. An populo facete laoreet quo, ad fabellas expetenda referrentur est. Augue cotidieque vel an. Vix aliquid vivendo liberavisse ut, etiam euripidis ius no. Ei audiam corpora eos. Nihil eirmod omnesque vis et. Ut vide mundi definitiones vix, voluptua constituto mel <!--This is the "Interested in ..." paragraph--></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   #salepoint {
   float: right;
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 48%;
}

#about {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 48%;
}
```